# Receiving an error for invalid number of arguments from Hardhat contract deployment?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Receiving this error from Hardhat's logger when attempting to deploy an ETH smart contract using Hardhat locally. I'm attempting to run two different contracts through Hardhat's deploy.js script.
[image: deploy.js]

However, I do receive this error in regards to arguments:

Error: missing argument:  in Contract constructor (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2

Here's a look at the contract itself, Greeter.sol:
[image: Greeter.sol]

Here's a screenshot of a console.log of the arguments I'm receiving
[image: Arguments console log]

Comment: Hi TimeoWilliams! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! The next time you ask a question it is better to include the code as text, that way it will be much easier to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I shouldn't have invoked Greeter.deploy() two different times in the first version of deploy.js. Silly mistake

[image: updated_deploy.js]